# dont have iphone simulator folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Some months ago when the newest iphone simulator version was 4.3.1, I removed the iphone simulator folder from my hard drive to an external hard drive.

Now when I drag it back again the version was still 4.3.1 so I cant use it for saving media on it.

Is it possible to like reinstall something to get the newest version (6.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To confirm that the install location of the iOS Simulator:** In XCode 4.5.2 (and most other recent versions of XCode, not sure when this was first introduced), the iOS Simulator is installed at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications
```

With the current version of the iOS Simulator, there aren't separate applications for different iOS versions.  Instead you use the menu option "Hardware" -> "Version" to select a different iOS version to simulate.

**If it's the "Application Support" folder that is missing** (where simulator copies of your apps get "installed"), you might check:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

Note: Mountain Lion now hides the "Library" folder from the default Finder view.  It's easy enough to look in that path for a "6.0" (or other iOS Simulator version) folder to see if yours exists there.

**Finally, if really need a fresh copy of the iOS Simulator**, to install another version (assuming XCode 4.5.2 or similar):
"XCode" menu -> "Preferences" -> "Downloads" tab -> Select another Simulator you'd like to install

[image]